# Jenkins on Windows can't see folder names prefixed with a '.'

Tags: windows, jenkins

So I'm still fairly new to Jenkins (on Windows version 2.10) but and I'm completely lost as to why I'm failing to see folders prefixed with a period. Basically I spent most of my day trying to figure out why script was failing when run from Jenkins but not when I ran it myself and it was failing because it couldn't find a file that clearly exists but was behind a folder with with a . in front of it (ex 'C:\Temp.Tacos').

I've gone to the Jenkins CLI and tried running commands like this

print "cmd /c dir C:\Temp".execute().text

and have it not list the folder despite it listed as expected outside of Jenkins. What's going on here and is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: You're probably going to want to do two things here. First, avoid any names that start with a period unless you intend them to be hidden (e.g., .git, .hg, .htaccess), since that is the convention on all *nix systems. Second, you probably don't want to run Jenkins in Windows at all. That's going to give you fits, based on my personal experience. You should set up a Linux system, such as a VM, Vagrant instance, or Docker instance, and run it in that. It will be much easier.

Comment: In you CLI example the backslashes in the path should be escaped with another backslash. Also I'd usually use ProcessBuilder as it allows to evacute stderr on errors: `cmd='script stuff here'; println new ProcessBuilder('cmd', '/C', cmd).redirectErrorStream(true).start().text`.

Comment: To Ed, I'm aware of those Unix conventions you mention however even if it were to follow those conventions it believe it should still find the file given an absolute path.  Also I'm going to want to stay on Windows even if it isn't supported as well since all the software I'm building is Windows specific.

Comment: To izzekil, thanks for the advice I'll try that out next time I need to run terminal commands in the CLI.

Comment: I now believe the problem to be something else entirely, I'll update when I know more.